# How to replace the "underline" set in css using a class within a p tag

Tags: html, css

I want to use a class element in a `<span>` tag that is underneath the `<p>` tag to replace the underline set in the parent-level `<p>` tag. Below is my code:

```css
#instru_topp p span:last-child {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="instru_topp">
  <h3>The topping</h3>
  <p><span class="especial">Mix</span> all the -- <span>Ingredients</span> and pour it on the top cake. After bakin it, you will end up with this:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is - where are the italics you are trying to override?  Also you say you want to use the class of the first span but that's not in your css selector and you use last-child instead of first? Please could you edit your snippet with a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: can you elaborate more? which part of the code use italics? If you want to point specifically to the span with class "especial", you simply can use `.especial {/* your code here */}` or more specific like `#instru_topp p span.especial {/* your code here */}`

Comment: @user221459 The answer to this question is to set `font-style: normal !important;` for the class `especial` in the CSS. `!important` makes it override the previous stylings.